# DeleteMessagesAsync Discord.net

Tags: .net, discord.net

im using Discord.net (V1.0.1),

trying to convert (v0.9.6) but faced error.(delete last messages)

(v0.9.6) codes
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpCMx.png)

my code :

```
Private Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task

    If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
        'nothing
    Else

        If message.Content.Contains("clear") Then
            Dim mssg() As Discord.MessageSource = Await DeleteMessagesAsync(100)

        End If
    End If

    End Function
```

> Error : Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30451 'DeleteMessagesAsync' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: The method you are looking for is under ITextChannel as DeleteMessagesAsync. See the documentation of this method [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.ITextChannel.html#Discord_ITextChannel_DeleteMessagesAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Discord_IMessage__Discord_RequestOptions_)

Comment: i already looked there, but it still hard to understand as well Oo

Comment: What you need to do is get the messages you wish to delete via an instance of text channel using [GetMessagesAsync](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketTextChannel.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketTextChannel_GetMessagesAsync_System_Int32_Discord_RequestOptions_) and then pass the said messages to the `DeleteMessagesAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea, this is for Discord.net V2.x

This retrieves a list of messages default 100 from the channel the command was used in then attempts to delete.

If any of the messages are older than 2 weeks it will fail so will need to add the exceptions in to capture

```
IEnumerable<IMessage> var = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(input).FlattenAsync();
((ITextChannel)Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(var)
```